# In google play console APK details, what "differentiating" and "common" mean for native platforms?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an apk on my google play console, and when I look at the apk details, it show this :

> Native platforms 1 differentiating: arm64-v8a + 1 common: armeabi-v7a

The apk has 2 cpu architectures embedded (arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a) , with a couple of .so libraries provided (each native library is provided for both architecture). But I don't understand why **arm64-v8a** would b "**differentiating**" and **armeabi-v7a** would be "**common**". Any clue ?

Screenshot of the google play console :
[image]